# Alphanumeric NOP implementation

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Looking for a NOP alternative in an alphanumeric form in order to test a buffer overflow through an IDS. The IDS will encode non-alphanumeric values such as `0x90` to `%90` to meet HTTP RFC standards hence the reason to instead try an alphanumeric iteration. An alphanumeric payload has been created but the exploit code uses `memset` and `0x90` to fill the buffer. Exploit code [here](http://downloads.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities/exploits/ghttp.c).

The page [here](http://www.asmpedia.org/index.php?title=NOP) provides some multi-byte options but I am not sure how to replace the NOP byte (around line 147) with something like `x0f\x1f\x00` or anything else that might provide a sled for the payload in the code referenced above. Any recommendations?

Comment: You cannot, you need a loop to fill in the buffer. x86 NOP instruction and several other x86 instructions, are instructions that takes up exactly 1 byte. Other x86 instructions may take up more bytes.

Comment: assuming x86, you can just insert multiple 1byte nops

Comment: @KeithThompson Intel x86 and need to evade an IDS so that will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a [great site](https://nets.ec/Ascii_shellcode#Instructions) listing all sorts of ASCII assembly instructions (including ASCII nops), if you're curious. Using these instructions, you can construct entire programs that consist of only ASCII characters. In the context of black hat work, these instructions are very handy for getting around intrusion detection systems and text filters.

For example, the sequence `ABCDEFGIJKLMNO` is an x86 no-op, despite basically looking like an alphabetical sequence. Furthermore, if you don't care about trashing certain registers, you can create sequences of ASCII instructions which do nothing more than increment or decrement those registers.

If you're trying to build a nop-sled using these multibyte nops, be aware that (AFAIK) it's not possible to make a true nop-sled without using `nop` which can be entered at any byte offset and still perform a precise no-op. However, using a pair of instructions like `AI` (`inc ecx; dec ecx`) is safer than using a multibyte NOP sequence since the sequence just trashes a register if entered at the wrong offset (whereas a multibyte NOP might cause an illegal instruction exception or do something unexpected).

Anyway, here's how you can, in general, replicate any multibyte sequence across a buffer in C (provided `sizeof(buffer)` is a multiple of the op length):

```
/* I find string notation to be more convenient, but it means using `sizeof(op)-1` to get the op length */
static char op[] = "\xaa\xbb\xcc";

char buffer[3072];
int i;

for(i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)
    buffer[i] = op[i%(sizeof(op)-1)];
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the question with a reference to the code. Do you still think there might be a way to use a pair of instructions or multibyte NOP sequence to replace the without using the NOP? If so, have an implementation recommendation?

Comment: As my post explains, you can use a sequence like "AI" to form a nop (keeping in mind that any multibyte sequence might clobber a register if entered at an odd offset).

Comment: @PeadarÓDuinnín: Thank you; I've replaced it.

Comment: @nneoneo No worries. I've would've done but I was rushing to finish an assignment. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to have a multi-byte NOP sequence (and assuming that `0f 1f 00` *is* such a sequence), you need to do it in a loop, something like:

```
char cycle[] = { '\x0f', '\x1f', '\x00' };
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)
    buffer[i] = cycle[i%3];
```

That's probably not going to do what you expect is the `buffer` size isn't exactly a multiple of three bytes but you can use the 1-byte NOPs at the end in that case:

```
int i = -1;
char cycle[] = { '\x0f', '\x1f', '\x00' };
while (++i < sizeof(buffer) - (sizeof(buffer) % 3))
    buffer[i] = cycle[i%3];
while (i < sizeof(buffer))
    buffer[i++] = '\x90';
```

You can't do it with a `memset` since that function works by setting every byte to a specific value, it will not allow you to set alternating bytes to different values.